# Use JQuery to hide all but two rows (tr) in a table

Tags: jquery, html-table, tablerow

I have a table like this:

```
<table class="tableclass">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <th>..</th>
       <th>..</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
       <td>..<</td>
       <td>..<</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr class="even">
       <td>..<</td>
       <td>..<</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr class="odd current">
       <td>..<</td>
       <td>..<</td>
    </tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

There are many tr that have odd or even class, and they can be before or after tr that has current class.

I want to hide all but two rows below:

1. The row (tr) that has "current" class
2. The row (tr) that has <th>

In other words, I want the table becomes

```
<table class="tableclass">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <th>..</th>
       <th>..</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd current">
       <td>..<</td>
       <td>..<</td>
    </tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I try to use

```
$("table.tableclass tr:not(.current)").hide();
```

But it hides tr that has th inside too.

Is there an AND operator?  Something like

```
$("table.tableclass tr:not(.current) AND tr:not(WITH NO CLASS)").hide();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to scope your selector to hide only odd/even classes but not current. so you are almost there.

```
$("table.tableclass tr.odd:not(.current), table.tableclass tr.even:not(.current)").hide()
```

Comment: No prob, don't forget to accept answer if its the right one :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$("table .odd,.even").hide()
```

or individually you can hide like

```
$(".odd").hide();
$(".even").hide();
```

Comment: it will hides .odd,.even class rows but the remaining .current,no class rows

Answer (score 0):

Why not change `<tr><th></th></tr>` to `<thead><th></th></thead>` and move this above the `<tbody></tbody>`? Anyway, it should be there.